# Find maximum of a polynomial?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, optimization

How would I find the value of p which the function f is the maximum:

$f(p)= 100 p(1-p)^{99}$  $p\geq0$

And in general, can setting the derivative equal to $0$ and solving for the variable lead to the values in function's domain that produces the maximum value ?

Comment: On what interval?

Comment: Note that $(p) <0$ for $p \notin [0,1]$, so you need only consider $p$ on the interval $[0,1]$. There is exactly one $p \in [0,1]$ at which $f'(p) = 0$, hence this **must** be the maximum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, yes. This is known as the ["Fermat's Theorem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_(stationary_points)). Of course, you have to check with the second derivative test to see if you found a maximum or minimum. You could also get a saddle point, which is effectively a place where the graph is flat... see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saddle_point).

Let's find the maximum of your function:
$$f(p)= 100 p(1-p)^{99}$$
$$f'(p) = 100 (1-p)^{99}-9900 (1-p)^{98} p$$
Now set the derivative to $0$:
$$0 = 100 (1-p)^{99}-9900 (1-p)^{98} p$$
$$0=-100(p-1)^{98}(100p-1)$$
$$(p-1)^{98} =0 \;\text{ or } \;100p-1 = 0$$
$$p = 1 \;\text{ or } \;p = \frac{1}{100}$$
After some checking we find the second solution is the global maximum, giving a value of $\approx 0.36973$. Thus, we find that the maximum is around the point $(0.01,0.36973)$

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way;  clearly we seek $p \in (0, 1)$, so $p, 1-p$ are both positive.
$$\frac{99}{100}f(p) = (99p) \cdot \underbrace{(1-p)(1-p)\cdots(1-p)}_{99 \text{ times}} $$

Now the RHS is the product of $100$ terms, which sum to a constant, viz. $99$.  Therefore its maximum is when all terms are equal, viz. $\dfrac{99}{100}$ (this can be shown easily with AM-GM).  $\implies p = \dfrac1{100}$.